# How to retrive data from Table hibernate in my case?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I'm building a web site using `Spring MVC`.
I have these `tables` :

```
zebra (idzebra,nom,snum,niveau2) 

niveau2(idniveau2,nom,date,annee) 

annee(idannee,num)
```

I want to list all `data binding`

```
<td class="center">${zebra.getNiveau2().getAnnee().getNum() }</td>
<td class="center">${zebra.getNiveau2().getSemaine().getNum() }</td>
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.getAnnee()
    javax.el.Util.findWrapper(Util.java:370)
    javax.el.Util.findMethod(Util.java:216)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:147)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.semaine.semaine_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(semaine_jsp.java:708)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.semaine.semaine_jsp._jspService(semaine_jsp.java:394)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What to do? and thank you

Comment: Have you tried ${zebra.niveau2.annee.num} instead?

Comment: no that will not work, it should be with the get methodes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the property names directly and not the getter methods, the below code works perfectly :

```
<c:forEach items="${facilities}" var="facility">
                <tr>
                    <td>${facility.name}</td>
                    <td>${facility.code}</td>
                    <td>${facility.linkedInterface.name}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

*** EDIT ***

I don't believe your entity class has anything to do with this issue.  How are you providing the object to the model?  As long as you have a valid object / list you are providing to your JSP this should work.  My entity class' properties are all private and this still works, i believe reflection is used to access the fields.  This is how my controller works for this page :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewFacilities(ModelMap model) 
{
    List<Interface> interfaces = interfaceService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("interfaces", interfaces);

    List<Facility> facilities = facilityService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("facilities", facilities);

    setPermissions(model);

    return "facilities";
}
```

Comment: can you post the annotition of the tables please

Answer (score 0):

Getters setters are only used on server side to get and set the values.

If you want to get values in your view page(for ex. jsp) then you can access directly with dot operator, so in your case it will be like

```
${zebra.niveau2.annee.num}
```

**NOTE:** *In above code i am assuming like niveau2,annee,num are direct property fields(String,int etc) but not objects. If those are objects then you need to iterate using for loop.*